# Looking for a story about a scientist that makes a gift for child, a tiny box "containing" a large new pet

Tags: story-identification

A scientist makes a tiny box as a gift for his or her child. The tiny box apparently distorts space and leads to another dimension or something.  The child is supposed to pull some sort of large (bigger than the dimensions of the box) pet creature out of that box.

> But instead the child gets pulled into the box, apparently lost.

Comment: any possibility it's related to [this other box](http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2010/163/8/8/Bigger_on_the_inside_by_JamusDu.jpg) that's bigger on the inside

Comment: No, definitely not Dr. Who. The short story was in an anthology I read in the early-to-mid 1970s.

Comment: +1 this story seems really interesting

Comment: Is this the same story? If so we have more details to go on now. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177880/please-help-me-id-this-70s-sf-horror-story-about-a-monster-in-a-little-box

Comment: Both of us are definitely looking for the same story

Comment: Agreed. It's highly likely that I read it in a publication by Scholastic, or something similar.

Comment: I spent my entire day today going through microfilm archives of READ Magazine from Sept. 1971-May 1977. Didn't find it. So it must have been in Weekly Reader or some even more ephemeral publication.